# Django - Page not found (404) for URL

Tags: django

I am getting the following error when ever I access the url's except /home.

```
Page not found (404) 
Request Method: GET Request URL

Using the URLconf defined
in report_ui.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/ 
^home/ 
The current URL, individual/, didn't match any of
these. You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your
Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a
standard 404 page.
```

The code :
**urls.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('dnslog.views',
    # Examples:
    url(r'$', 'home'),
    url(r'^report/$', 'report'),
    url(r'^angular/$', 'angular'),
    url(r'^linear/$', 'LinearPrediction'),
    url(r'^splunk/$', 'splunkdata'),
    url(r'^toyprediction/$', 'toyprediction'),
    url(r'^saleprediction/$', 'GetSalesPrediction'),
    url(r'^customerprediction/$', 'GetCustomerPrediction'),
    url(r'^monthwiseprediction/$', 'GetMonthWiseSalesPrediction'),
    url(r'^getlinearprediction/(?P<duration>.\w+)/$', 'GetLinearPrediction'),
    url(r'^getprediction/$', 'GetPredictionReport'),
    url(r'^modeldata/(?P<obj>.\w+)/$', 'GetConsolidatedObjectData'),
#    url(r'^modeldata/(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', 'GetConsolidatedObjectData'),
    url(r'^home/(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', 'GetConsolidateHits'),
    url(r'^bytes/$', 'BytesDownload'),
    url(r'^BytesDownload/(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$',
        'GetConsolidateDownloadBytes'),
    url(r'^getCntPerData/$', 'GetConsolidateCntPer'),
    url(r'^help/$', 'help'),
    url(r'^individualhits/$', 'individualhits'),
    url(r'^individualhits1/(?P<empid>.+)/(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$',
         'GetIndividualHits'),
    url(r'^bubble/$', 'bubble'),
    url(r'^bubblechart/(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$',
        'GetConsolidateHitsForBubble'),
    #url(r'^test/$', 'test'),
    url(r'^domaincloud/$', 'cloud'),
    url(r'^getdomaincloud/(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', 'Getclouddata'),
    url(r'^circleview/$', 'circle'),
    url(r'^getcircleview/(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', 'Getcircledata'),
    url(r'^comparisionview/$', 'comparision'),
    url(r'^getcomparision/(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', 'Getcomparisiondata'),
    url(r'^individualcomparision/(?P<domain>.+)/(?P<empid>.+)/(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$',
 'GetIndividualComparisonData'),
    url(r'^trendview/$', 'trend'),
    url(r'^gettrendview/$', 'Gettrenddata'),
    url(r'^zoomabletree/$', 'zoomabletree'),
    url(r'^getzoomabletree/(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', 'Getcircledata'),
    ##url(r'^report_ui/', include('report_ui.foo.urls')),
    #url(r'^individualConsolidatedHits/$', 'individualConsolidatedHits'),
    url(r'^getConsolidatedCategoryDetails/(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$',
                                             'getConsolidatedCategoryDetails'),
    # overall individual reports
    url(r'^individual/$', 'individual'),
    ## individual Category report
    #url(r'^individualcategory/$', 'individualcategory'),
    url(r'^GetIndividualCategory/(?P<empid>.+)/(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$',
         'GetIndividualCategory'),
    url(r'^twitter/$','twitter'),
```

**root urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# to include the media url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'report_ui.views.home', name='home'),
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     url(r'^home/', include('dnslog.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),


)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Either change your root urls.py

```
  url(r'^home/', include('dnslog.urls')),
```

to:

```
 url(r'^/', include('dnslog.urls')),
```

Or change your request from

from:

```
individual/
```

to:

```
 /home/individual
```

Comment: I tried the request as "/home/individual". The problem here is I still see home page instead of the "individual" page. Changing the root urls.py throwed Page not found error.